# Не выводятся значения атрибутов

Tags: html, css

Почему для тега `select` не выводится значение атрибута `style`?  Все теги закрыты.

[image: html template]

[image: my notice]

Comment: по какому принципу работает подсветка кода? По пробуй добавить пробел после `:`

Comment: Не надо постить код картинками. Нужно просто скопировать его в тело вопроса.

Comment: @Grundy не работает.

Comment: твоя разметка не соответствует итоговому html, значит либо ты смотришь другой кусок кода, либо разметка дополнительно обрабатывается на клиенте

Comment: почему `class` не совпадает?

Comment: @Grundy класы добавляються с с помощью JS

Comment: @ПетроЧайківський, именно поэтому и не выводится style, вернее сбрасывается его значение.